# Join Point to the Nearest Polygon

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, spatial-join

I'm using QGis 2.18.3 on Windows 10.

I'm trying to join a point layer with a polygon layer. However, since it is a city grid map, points that do not fall within the polygons do not get joined.

My expectation was that QGis could join those points to the nearest polygon.

Can somebody help me with that?

Here's a picture of my map.

[image]

Comment: Do you have GRASS tools enabled in processing? There is the v.distance tool available there if you do.

Comment: And just to be clear, are you looking to attach the point attributes to the polygons or attach the polygon attributes to the points?

Answer (score 3):

Could you take a look at the NNJoin plugin that can be installed from QGIS:

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/NNJoin/

Hope this helps.
Cheers,

Lluís

Answer (score 1):

If you're points are "really close" to the polygons (not in the middle of the roads), then you can "inflate" the size of the polygons by using "Buffer" transformations, and then intersect with the inflated polygons.

If you inflate too far, you may end up haing one point assigned to multple polygons - you need to check that's not hapening, or have a use case where it would not be a problem.