# Importing multiple CSV-files without coordinates into schema in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, csv, import, australia, postal-code

I have multiple CSV-files that I need to import into a database in QGIS 2.18.

The data contains Australian Postal Code information hence does not have x,y (lat/long) coordinates in it.

How can I load all those files into a database?

Comment: @user2856 done. I meant to add all those csv files with no geometry  into a database

Comment: Is QGIS 2.18 a necessity? Or you can also deploy a QGIS 3? Simply saying YES you can get a "x/y"-coordinates out of a Postal codes, (i) as a Polygon in WKT-format or (ii) as a geocentroid of that polygon in `"x/y"`-tuples, but would it be sufficient enough for you? Can you provide a sample of that data in csv? Are you okay with some coding or looking for a code free solution?

Comment: Moreover, if you are willing to import csv-files with no geometry into a database, maybe the GIS SE is not the best place to ask this question, because you do not have a "georeferenced" context, IMHO the [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) can assist you in that. As well as when you mention a database it is highly required to specify that database name/type/configuration etc.

Comment: Additionally you may try [this solutions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/300619/99589) provided by @csk, but in your case look for Australian Postal Code Data (maybe [this is your choice](https://www.matthewproctor.com/australian_postcodes) or [this one](https://www.corra.com.au/australian-postcode-location-data/)) instead of the property ownership (parcel) polygon data as was mentioned by@csk.