# QGIS (or Pelias): geocode PHI locally, not with a web service

Tags: qgis, geocoding

I have protected health information (PHI) and need to geocode locally, not using a web service (a HIPAA violation). I used to do this with ArcGIS, but my license has expired, and I would like to move to QGIS or Pelias.

We are having server issues installing Pelias, but QGIS is working just fine, so that is my preference.

I had public (non-PHI) latitude/longitude data (area crime events). I was able to successfully spatially join the crime latitude/longitude with census tract shapefiles to get crime census tract.

However, my PHI address information is Street Address (one field for number and street), City, State, Zip. All tutorials send this to the web (not an option).

In addition to my census tract shapefiles, I also downloaded open street maps data (that's what Pelias was going to use), if that helps.

I successfully geocoded fake address data, but only via web service.

Comment: You can try using the [Geocoder in QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#batch-nominatim-geocoder), if it is not what you actually meant by *"geocode locally"* then you can try to find that data somewhere online and join by address using e.g. Excel or anything else locally? Check also this topic: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/300619/99589

Comment: I have purchased a property boundary file from regrid to allow geocoding without using a web service. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the property boundary datafile only matched 15K of my 500K patient addresses. So I'm still looking for hipaa compliant geocoding resources.